# Arrow before and after a box with CSS

Tags: css, css-shapes

I'm trying to create in a single box, two arrows, one as a pointer and the other one into the box just behind.

Can not find the way to get the arrow right behind.

Someone can help me??

here i post the link with the sample: http://jsfiddle.net/7Esu2/

CSS:

```
.arrow {
    width:210px;
    height:40px;
    background-color:#CBCBCB;
    border: 1px solid #CBCBCB;
    position:relative;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:20px;
    font-weight:bold;
    line-height:40px;
}
.arrow:after {
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    top:-1px;
    left:210px;
    width:0;
    height:0;
    border:21px solid transparent;
    border-left:15px solid #CBCBCB;
}
.arrow:before {
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    top:-1px;
    left:211px;
    width:0;
    height:0;
    border:21px solid transparent;
    border-left:15px solid #CBCBCB;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="arrow">
    FLECHA
</div>
```

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve? you already have to arrows at almost the same position. maybe just move one of them elsewhere :) ?

Comment: I need the space right behind the box with the same shape than the arrow.

Comment: something like this http://jsfiddle.net/7Esu2/1/ ?

Comment: I actually prefer using inline blocks, over absolutely positioning the before and after... also, this implementation preserves the transparent background at the tail of the arrow (rather than making it white like the above solution... http://jsfiddle.net/philwills/7Esu2/2/

Comment: Cool! Thanks @Phillip. Post to vote up!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I prefer using inline-blocks over absolute positioning. Also, :before and :after create child elements (inside) the element you specify them on (at the beginning and end). For this, it would probably be best to have a wrapper (or inner) block, like so:

```
<div class="arrow">
    <div class="inner-arrow">
        FLECHA
    </div>
</div>
```

Then the inner block is going to get most of the styling, as the wrapper is primarily there to contain the :before and :after. The wrapper (.arrow) needs to have font-size: 0 (or some other method to make the white-space around the inner block, .inner-arrow, go away).

```
.arrow {
    font-size: 0;
}
.inner-arrow {
    width:210px;
    height:40px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color:#CBCBCB;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:20px;
    font-weight:bold;
    line-height:40px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Most of the styles for .arrow:before and .arrow:after will be the same, so we'll group those. Then specify the differences below (they have to be below to override the common styles).

```
.arrow:before,
.arrow:after {
    content:'';
    display: inline-block;
    width:0;
    height:0;
    border:20px solid transparent;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.arrow:before {
    border-top-color: #CBCBCB;
    border-bottom-color: #CBCBCB;
    border-right-color: #CBCBCB;
}
.arrow:after {
    border-left-color: #CBCBCB;
}
```

This is all in the a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/philwills/7Esu2/2/).