# Create a button with double arrows at the end

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, button, css-shapes

I'm trying to achieve this effect for a button:

[image: Double Arrow Button]

I've been battling it for a couple hours and the best I could come up with was this [CodePen](http://codepen.io/tone4407/pen/MaONKJ).

```
<a href="#" class="btn-wrap">
  <span class="btn btn-primary">See the Proof</span>
</a>

.btn {
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.btn-primary {
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .2s ease;
    transition: all .2s ease;
}
.btn-primary:before, .btn-primary:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    right: -20px;
    width: 10px;
    height: 50%;
    background: inherit;
}
.btn-primary:before {
  top: 0;
  transform: skewX(30deg);
}
.btn-primary:after {
  bottom: 0;
  transform: skewX(-30deg);
}
.btn-wrap {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
.btn-wrap:before, .btn-wrap:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    right: -40px;
    width: 10px;
    height: 50%;
    background: #337ab7;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .2s ease;
    transition: all .2s ease;
}
.btn-wrap:hover:before, .btn-wrap:hover:after {
    background: #23527c;
}
.btn-wrap:before {
  top: 0;
  transform: skewX(30deg);
}
.btn-wrap:after {
  bottom: 0;
  transform: skewX(-30deg);
}
```

I want to ensure it works well responsively, so if the text breaks to 2 lines, the arrows maintain full height.

Any thoughts?

Comment: The method used in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27636373/how-to-make-this-arrow-in-css-only/28196665#28196665) would help you and also [this pen](http://codepen.io/hari_shanx/pen/avVExX).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **Note:** The approach that is used in the answer that [I linked in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33218348/double-arrow-button#comment54241141_33218348) is the best if you have to support all browsers. If IE support is not mandatory then you can use clip paths like in this answer. Could not post this approach in the other thread because its requirements are different and hence adding as answer here.

Using SVG `clipPath` along with the CSS `clip-path` property we can create a path such that it cuts out the unwanted portions from the button (the `a` tag).

**Pros:**

- Output is responsive as it is SVG based and can adapt even if the text spans more than a line.
- Only one element is required unlike three elements (like in [the pen](http://codepen.io/hari_shanx/pen/avVExX) that I provided in comments).
- The cuts are transparent as we are clipping the path and so this will work even when the `body` or the parent has a non-solid background.

**Cons:**

- Lack of [support](http://caniuse.com/#search=clipPath) for `clip-path` in any version of IE including Edge. Support for `clip-path` in Edge is Under consideration and may get implemented in future.

```css
body {
  background: gray;
}
a {
  display: block;
  background: rgb(255,126,0);
  color: white;
  width: 300px;
  min-height: 35px;
  padding: 4px 5% 4px 4px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 24px;
  -webkit-clip-path: url(#clipper);
  clip-path: url(#clipper);
}
```

```html
<svg width="0" height="0">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clipper" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <path d="M0,0 0.79,0 0.83,0.5 0.79,1 0.81,1 0.85,0.5 0.81,0 0.86,0 0.9,0.5 0.86,1 0.88,1 0.92,0.5 0.88,0 0.93,0 0.97,0.5 0.93,1 0,1z" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>
<a href="#" class="btn-wrap">
  <span class="btn btn-primary">See the proof</span>
</a>

<a href="#" class="btn-wrap">
  <span class="btn btn-primary">See the proof when there is large text</span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

Check this solution this uses a `pseudo-element` to create the right first triangle and two skewed pseudo-elements to create the extending parts,`box-shadow` is used to recreate them

```css
body {
  background: #3D3D3D;
}
.btn {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: tomato;
  display:block;
  position:relative;
  margin:50px;
  line-height:50px;
  color:#fff;
  text-decoration:none;
  font-size:20px;
}
.btn:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 35px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 35px solid transparent;
  border-left: 35px solid tomato;
  right:-35px;
  top:0px;
  }
.btn:before{
  position:absolute;
  content:"";
  width:15px;
  height:35px;
  background:tomato;
  transform:skew(45deg);
  right:-40px;
  top:0;
  box-shadow:25px 0 0 0 tomato;
  }
.btn_inner:after{
  position:absolute;
  content:"";
  width:15px;
  height:35px;
  transform:skew(-45deg);
  right:-40px;
  bottom:0;
  background:tomato;
  box-shadow:25px 0 0 0 tomato;
  }
```

```html
<a href="#" class="btn">
  <span class="btn_inner">Some Text</span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to combine it with that code:

```
#triangle-right {
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-top: 20px solid transparent;
border-left: 9px solid red;
border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
padding-right: 20px;
display: block;
}
```

that is a triangle.

Hope I could help.

Devlen