# How to make angled div with css only

Tags: css, html

Can anyone tell me how do I make divs like these?
I don't want use images
[image: Angled Divs]

Thanks for the help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27636373/how-to-make-this-arrow-in-css-only

Comment: Search 2mn … http://line25.com/tutorials/how-to-create-flat-style-breadcrumb-links-with-css

Comment: I've voted to close as duplicate because the overall approach would be the same (even though the one in linked thread has spaces in between each elements). Try to recreate based on the linked thread and if you are still stuck somewhere, [edit] in your code and more details into the question.