# Pure HTML/CSS list menu with "next" arrows

Tags: html, css, menu, tabs

I am trying to generate a pure HTML/CSS menu with arrows pointing to the right. As long as the active state is the first tab everything looks fine (http://jsfiddle.net/q03wma6u/). But when the active class moves to the second tab, the border and the arrow are not positioned togehter (http://jsfiddle.net/q03wma6u/1/).

Is there a way to generate this menu just using HTML/CSS?

```css
ol.tabs {
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s linear;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.3s linear;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s linear;
  transition: opacity 0.3s linear;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
ol.tabs li {
  position: relative;
  display: table-cell;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -moz-transition: background-color 0.3s linear;
  -o-transition: background-color 0.3s linear;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.3s linear;
  transition: background-color 0.3s linear;
}
ol.tabs li:after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  right: 6px;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  border: 1px solid #4a4a4a;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-left: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
ol.tabs li:last-child:after  {
  border: none;
}
ol.tabs li:last-child a:before {
  border: none;
}
ol.tabs li.active a {
  background-color: #fff;
  -moz-transition: background-color 0.3s linear;
  -o-transition: background-color 0.3s linear;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.3s linear;
  transition: background-color 0.3s linear;
}
ol.tabs li.active a:before {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 20px 0 20px 20px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #fff;
  -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}
ol.tabs li.active a:after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 20px 0 20px 20px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #ccc;
  -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}

ol.tabs li:first-child a:after {
  border: none;
}

ol.tabs li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 0px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  color: #4a4a4a;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
ol.tabs li a.disabled {
  cursor: initial;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-decoration: none;
}
ol.tabs li a.disabled:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<ol class="tabs">
  <li class="step1 active"><a href="#" data-next="step2" class="disabled">Step 1</a></li>
  <li class="step2"><a href="#" data-next="step3" class="disabled">Step 2</a></li>
  <li class="step3"><a href="#" data-next="ste4" class="disabled">Step 3</a></li>
  <li class="step4"><a href="#" data-next="step5" class="disabled">Step 4</a></li>
</ol>
```

Comment: My attempt here: http://jsfiddle.net/c2vescbw/. Awesome stuff. Can't get past this.

Comment: Very close to (and possibly close enough to be a duplicate of) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27636373/how-to-make-this-arrow-in-css-only/28196665#28196665

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How's this:

```css
.tabs {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.tabs a {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: #4a4a4a;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.tabs > li {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #7B7B7B;
  border-right: none;
  width: 140px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #cccccc;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: table;
}

.tabs > li:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  margin: -15px -13px;
  border-top: solid 1px #7B7B7B;
  border-right: solid 1px #7B7B7B;
  width: 25px;
  /* .tabs > li height/2 */
  height: 29px;
  /* .tabs > li height/sqrt(3) */
  transform: rotate(30deg) skewY(30deg);
  /* create a rhombus */
  -ms-transform: rotate(30deg) skewY(30deg);
  /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg) skewY(30deg);
  /* Safari and Chrome */
  background: #cccccc;
  /* 49.1deg = atan(1.15) = atan(height/width) */
  /* percentages are 100 - .tabs > li percentages*/
  content: '';
  z-index: 1;
}

.tabs > li:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 40px;
  background: #cccccc;
  content: '';
  z-index: 2;
}

.tabs > li.active,
.tabs > li.active:before,
.tabs > li.active:after {
  background: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<ol class="tabs">
  <li class="step1"><a href="#" data-next="step2" class="disabled">Step 1</a></li>
  <li class="step2 active"><a href="#" data-next="step3" class="disabled">Step 2</a></li>
  <li class="step3"><a href="#" data-next="ste4" class="disabled">Step 3</a></li>
  <li class="step4"><a href="#" data-next="step5" class="disabled">Step 4</a></li>
</ol>
```

Without borders and square end box for the end `li`:

```css
.tabs {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.tabs a {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: #4a4a4a;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.tabs > li {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  border-right: none;
  width: 140px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #cccccc;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: table;
}

.tabs > li:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  margin: -15px -13px;
  border-top: solid 1px #7B7B7B;
  border-right: solid 1px #7B7B7B;
  width: 25px;
  height: 29px;
  transform: rotate(30deg) skewY(30deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(30deg) skewY(30deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg) skewY(30deg);
  background: #cccccc;
  content: '';
  z-index: 1;
}

.tabs > li:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 40px;
  background: #cccccc;
  content: '';
  z-index: 2;
}

.tabs > li.active,
.tabs > li.active:before,
.tabs > li.active:after {
  background: #ffffff;
}


.tabs > li:last-child:before,
.tabs > li:last-child:after {display:none; content:none;}
```

```html
<ol class="tabs">
  <li class="step1"><a href="#" data-next="step2" class="disabled">Step 1</a></li>
  <li class="step2 active"><a href="#" data-next="step3" class="disabled">Step 2</a></li>
  <li class="step3"><a href="#" data-next="ste4" class="disabled">Step 3</a></li>
  <li class="step4"><a href="#" data-next="step5" class="disabled">Step 4</a></li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 2):

CSS

```css
.breadcrumb { 
   list-style: none; 
   overflow: hidden; 
   font: 18px Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
  }
  .breadcrumb li { 
   float: left; 
  }
  .breadcrumb li a {
   color: white;
   text-decoration: none; 
   padding: 10px 0 10px 55px;
   background: brown;                   /* fallback color */
   background: hsla(34,85%,35%,1); 
   position: relative; 
   display: block;
   float: left;
  }
  .breadcrumb li a:after { 
   content: " "; 
   display: block; 
   width: 0; 
   height: 0;
   border-top: 50px solid transparent;           /* Go big on the size, and let overflow hide */
   border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
   border-left: 30px solid hsla(34,85%,35%,1);
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   margin-top: -50px; 
   left: 100%;
   z-index: 2; 
  } 
  .breadcrumb li a:before { 
   content: " "; 
   display: block; 
   width: 0; 
   height: 0;
   border-top: 50px solid transparent;           /* Go big on the size, and let overflow hide */
   border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
   border-left: 30px solid white;
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   margin-top: -50px; 
   margin-left: 1px;
   left: 100%;
   z-index: 1; 
  } 
  .breadcrumb li:first-child a {
   padding-left: 10px;
  }
  
  
  .breadcrumb li a:hover { background: hsla(34,85%,25%,1); }
  .breadcrumb li a:hover:after { border-left-color: hsla(34,85%,25%,1) !important; }
```

```html
<ul class="breadcrumb">
   <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Vehicles</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Vans</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Camper Vans</a></li>
   
  </ul>
```

change your css as mentioned in blow link

https://css-tricks.com/examples/TriangleBreadcrumbs/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10484792)

Comment: essential parts of the answer