# Add a border to the shape in CSS

Tags: html, css, shapes

I have a shape been rendered using CSS. I want to add a black border(#000) on the shape created. Thanks for your help.

[Codesandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/html-code-editor-forked-y7uvd?file=/index.html)

```css
.arrow-pointer {
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #32557f;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 25px;
  color: #fff;
}

.arrow-pointer:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 25px solid #fff;
  border-top: 25px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
}

.arrow-pointer:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: -25px;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 25px solid #32557f;
  border-top: 25px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div style="display:flex">
  <div class="arrow-pointer"></div>
  <div class="arrow-pointer"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I recommend you to use and SVG as background-inline instead. There is no easy way to do this, it would be a hacky css.

Comment: Can't very well put a border on a border. :) Box shadow won't work, either.

Comment: The answer on this post looks simular to your question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35280191/border-on-custom-shape.

Comment: I was about to suggest SVG as well. Failing that you could have a slightly larger black arrow behind the blue one.