# css skewed arrow box with transparent background

Tags: css, shapes

[image]

Basically thats the shape I want to create in CSS, the height is 192 and I want the background to be transparent.

Can I do this in CSS and if so is it smarter to do with SVG maybe?

Thanks

Comment: You may find the approach used in my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27636373/how-to-make-this-arrow-in-css-only/28196665#28196665) also helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

linear-gradient maybe ?

```css
div {
margin-top:50px;/*snippet button ! */
  padding: 0.5em 3.2%;
  font-size:20px;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(60deg,  transparent 3%, #49FFCE 3%, #49FFCE 97%, transparent 97%) no-repeat top, 
    linear-gradient(-60deg, transparent 3%, lime 3%, lime 97%, transparent 97%) no-repeat bottom;
  
  background-size: 100% 50%;
}
```

```html
<div>test
</div>
```