# Responsive Arrow Breadcrumb Navigation

Tags: html, css, css-shapes, breadcrumbs

So I have a breadcrumb nav that are arrows spaced apart. The tricky thing is I need it to be responsive. I think I am close messing around using vh and vw, but the issue I am running into is the white spacer not responding like the arrow before it. Any suggestions? Or is there a better way to handle it? I have tried a bunch of things but none seem to work. Any help is greatly appreciated. Fiddle is included

https://jsfiddle.net/8v9ctam0/

```css
/* ----------------------
    
General Styling
    
------------------------*/
    
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
    
.cd-breadcrumb, .cd-multi-steps {
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  margin: 1em auto;
  background-color: #edeff0;
  border-radius: .25em;
}
.cd-breadcrumb:after, .cd-multi-steps:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
.cd-breadcrumb li, .cd-multi-steps li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0.5em 0;
}
.cd-breadcrumb li::after, .cd-multi-steps li::after {
  /* this is the separator between items */
  display: inline-block;
  content: '\00bb';
  margin: 0 .6em;
  color: #959fa5;
}
.cd-breadcrumb li:last-of-type::after, .cd-multi-steps li:last-of-type::after {
  /* hide separator after the last item */
  display: none;
}
.cd-breadcrumb li > *, .cd-multi-steps li > * {
  /* single step */
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.0vw;
  color: #2c3f4c;
}
.cd-breadcrumb li.current > *, .cd-multi-steps li.current > * {
  /* selected step */
  color: #96c03d;
}
.no-touch .cd-breadcrumb a:hover, .no-touch .cd-multi-steps a:hover {
  /* steps already visited */
  color: #96c03d;
}
.cd-breadcrumb.custom-separator li::after, .cd-multi-steps.custom-separator li::after {
  /* replace the default arrow separator with a custom icon */
  content: '';
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  background: url(../img/cd-custom-separator.svg) no-repeat center center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.cd-breadcrumb.custom-icons li > *::before, .cd-multi-steps.custom-icons li > *::before {
  /* add a custom icon before each item */
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  margin-right: .4em;
  margin-top: -2px;
  background: url(../img/cd-custom-icons-01.svg) no-repeat 0 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.cd-breadcrumb.custom-icons li:not(.current):nth-of-type(2) > *::before, .cd-multi-steps.custom-icons li:not(.current):nth-of-type(2) > *::before {
  /* change custom icon using image sprites */
  background-position: -20px 0;
}
.cd-breadcrumb.custom-icons li:not(.current):nth-of-type(3) > *::before, .cd-multi-steps.custom-icons li:not(.current):nth-of-type(3) > *::before {
  background-position: -40px 0;
}
.cd-breadcrumb.custom-icons li:not(.current):nth-of-type(4) > *::before, .cd-multi-steps.custom-icons li:not(.current):nth-of-type(4) > *::before {
  background-position: -60px 0;
}
.cd-breadcrumb.custom-icons li.current:first-of-type > *::before, .cd-multi-steps.custom-icons li.current:first-of-type > *::before {
  /* change custom icon for the current item */
  background-position: 0 -20px;
}
.cd-breadcrumb.custom-icons li.current:nth-of-type(2) > *::before, .cd-multi-steps.custom-icons li.current:nth-of-type(2) > *::before {
  background-position: -20px -20px;
}
.cd-breadcrumb.custom-icons li.current:nth-of-type(3) > *::before, .cd-multi-steps.custom-icons li.current:nth-of-type(3) > *::before {
  background-position: -40px -20px;
}
.cd-breadcrumb.custom-icons li.current:nth-of-type(4) > *::before, .cd-multi-steps.custom-icons li.current:nth-of-type(4) > *::before {
  background-position: -60px -20px;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .cd-breadcrumb, .cd-multi-steps {
    padding: 0 1.2em;
  }
  .cd-breadcrumb li, .cd-multi-steps li {
    margin: 1.2em 0;
  }
  .cd-breadcrumb li::after, .cd-multi-steps li::after {
    margin: 0 1em;
  }
}


/* -------------------------------- 

Triangle breadcrumb

-------------------------------- */

  .cd-breadcrumb.triangle {
    /* reset basic style */
    background-color: transparent;
    padding: 0;
  }
    
  .cd-breadcrumb.triangle li {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
  }
    
  .checkout {
    max-height: 5.0vh;
    line-height: 2.5vh;
  }
      
  .cd-breadcrumb.triangle li strong {
    display: block;
  }
    
  .cd-breadcrumb.triangle li:last-of-type {
    margin-right: 0;
  }
  .cd-breadcrumb.triangle li > * {
    position: relative;
    padding: 1em .8em 1em 2.5em;
    color: #2c3f4c;
    background-color: #edeff0;
    /* the border color is used to style its ::after pseudo-element */
    border-color: #edeff0;
  }
  .cd-breadcrumb.triangle li.current > * {
    /* selected step */
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #F00;
    border-color: #F00;
  }
  .cd-breadcrumb.triangle li:first-of-type > * {
    padding-left: 1.6em;
  }
  .cd-breadcrumb.triangle li:last-of-type > * {
    padding-right: 1.6em;
  }
  .no-touch .cd-breadcrumb.triangle a:hover {
    /* steps already visited */
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #2c3f4c;
    border-color: #2c3f4c;
  }
  .cd-breadcrumb.triangle li::after, .cd-breadcrumb.triangle li > *::after {
    /* 
     li > *::after is the colored triangle after each item
     li::after is the white separator between two items
    */
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    content: '';
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    /* 48px is the height of the <a> element */
    border: 2.1em solid transparent;
    border-right-width: 0;
    border-left-width: 0.8em;
  }
  .cd-breadcrumb.triangle li::after {
    /* this is the white separator between two items */
    z-index: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(8px);
    -moz-transform: translateX(8px);
    -ms-transform: translateX(8px);
    -o-transform: translateX(8px);
    transform: translateX(8px);
    border-left-color: #ffffff;
    /* reset style */
    margin: 0;
  }
  .cd-breadcrumb.triangle li > *::after {
    /* this is the colored triangle after each element */
    z-index: 2;
    border-left-color: inherit;
  }
  .cd-breadcrumb.triangle li:last-of-type::after, .cd-breadcrumb.triangle li:last-of-type > *::after {
    /* hide the triangle after the last step */
    display: none;
  }
  .cd-breadcrumb.triangle.custom-separator li::after {
    /* reset style */
    background-image: none;
  }
  .cd-breadcrumb.triangle.custom-icons li::after, .cd-breadcrumb.triangle.custom-icons li > *::after {
    /* 50px is the height of the <a> element */
    border-top-width: 25px;
    border-bottom-width: 25px;
  }

  @-moz-document url-prefix() {
    .cd-breadcrumb.triangle li::after,
    .cd-breadcrumb.triangle li > *::after {
      /* fix a bug on Firefix - tooth edge on css triangle */
      border-left-style: dashed;
    }
  }
```

```html
<body>
<section>
 <nav>
  <ol class="cd-breadcrumb triangle">
   <li><a href="#0" class="checkout"><strong>Checkout</strong></a></li>
            <li class="current"><a href="#0"><strong>Step 1:</strong>Account</a></li>
   <li><a href="#0"><strong>Step 2:</strong>Shipping</a></li>
   <li><a href="#0"><strong>Step 3:</strong>Payment & Place Order</a></li>
   <li><a href="#0"><strong>Step 4:</strong>Confirmation</a></li>
  </ol>
 </nav>
</section>
</body>
```

Comment: [**This answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27636373/how-to-make-this-arrow-in-css-only/28196665#28196665) might also help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use linear-gradient:

**run  the snippet in full page mode to increase or decrease font-size while resizing the window :)**

or play with at http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/aNNdyq

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
ol {
  display:table;/* to fit to content */
  overflow:hidden;/*  will hide bit arrow of last li if negative margin-right set there */
  white-space:nowrap;/* keep inline-block li on a single line */
  font-size:0.65em;
}
ol li {
  display:inline-block;/* be an inline boxe */
  margin-top:1em; /* get some air , optionnal */
  margin-right:-1.3em;/* overlay them to reduce white gap in between. tune in em to your needs */
  line-height:1.2em; /* tune to your needs */
  padding:1em 2em;/* should be fine with gradient bg */
  background:linear-gradient(70deg, transparent  1em, lightgray 1em, lightgray 50%, transparent 50%) top  left no-repeat,
    linear-gradient(-110deg, transparent 1em, lightgray 1em, lightgray 55%, transparent 55%) top   no-repeat,
    linear-gradient(-70deg, transparent  1em, lightgray 1em, lightgray 50%, transparent 50%) bottom  left no-repeat,
    linear-gradient(110deg, transparent 1em, lightgray 1em, lightgray 55%, transparent 55%) bottom   no-repeat;
  /*bg arrow color is lightgray, to chanage it, change each one of theme in gradient */
  background-size:100% 51.5% ;/* resize each piece a gradient to draw the shape */
  
}
ol li.current, ol li:hover {
   background:linear-gradient(70deg, transparent  1em, #FF0000 1em, #FF0000 50%, transparent 50%) top  left no-repeat,
    linear-gradient(-110deg, transparent 1em, #FF0000 1em, #FF0000 55%, transparent 55%) top   no-repeat,
    linear-gradient(-70deg, transparent  1em, #FF0000 1em, #FF0000 50%, transparent 50%) bottom  left no-repeat,
    linear-gradient(110deg, transparent 1em, #FF0000 1em, #FF0000 55%, transparent 55%) bottom   no-repeat;
  /* bg arrow color is now red */
  background-size:100% 51.5% ;
  }
ol li.current a, ol li:hover a {
  
  color:white;
  
}
a {
  text-decoration:none;
  color:orange;
  text-shadow:1px 1px 1px black,-1px -1px 1px gray;
  font-variant:small-caps;
  font-weight:bold;
  transition:0.2s;
}

@media all and (max-width:2700px) {html {font-size:50px;transition:1s;}}
@media all and (max-width:2000px) {html {font-size:45px;transition:1s;}}
@media all and (max-width:1600px) {html {font-size:30px;transition:1s;}}
@media all and (max-width:1200px) {html {font-size:25px;transition:1s;}}
@media all and (max-width:1100px) {html {font-size:22px;transition:1s;}}
@media all and (max-width: 900px) {html {font-size:18px;transition:1s;}}
@media all and (max-width: 700px) {html {font-size:15px;transition:1s;}}
@media all and (max-width: 500px) {html {font-size:12px;transition:1s;}}
@media all and (max-width: 300px) {html {font-size: 8px;transition:1s;}}
```

```html
<body>
<section>
 <nav>
  <ol class="cd-breadcrumb triangle">
   <li><a href="#0" class="checkout"><strong>Checkout</strong></a></li>
            <li class="current"><a href="#0"><strong>Step 1:</strong>Account</a></li>
   <li><a href="#0"><strong>Step 2:</strong>Shipping</a></li>
   <li><a href="#0"><strong>Step 3:</strong>Payment & Place Order</a></li>
   <li><a href="#0"><strong>Step 4:</strong>Confirmation</a></li>
  </ol>
 </nav>
</section>
</body>
```

Comment: Would I be able to get this in a fiddle? or could I just copy the css you put in there? The animation seems to show it working, but id like to try dragging the results area on a fiddle or pen.

Comment: @OMGDrAcula Here is a codepen with a bunch of mediaqueries to test  : http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/aNNdyq (answer updated too )

Comment: Awesome! It looks to be working great except I see a white line in the middle of all the divs. In chrome at least.

Comment: @OMGDrAcula oh yes , chrome rounds down calculation, increase `background-size:100% 51.5%`

Comment: Will do thanks! Gonna accept this as the answer as it is the closest to what I need. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 3):

Here's a very simple way to make it, but it uses transform so your target browser has to support that property (most up-to-date browsers do).

[image]

```css
body {
 padding-top: 95px;
}

.crumb-trail {
 background-color: #CCD2D8;
 color: #62717C;
 list-style: none;
 padding: 0px;
 margin: auto;
 width: 80%;
}

.crumb {
 padding: 4px 16px;
 position: relative;
}


.crumb:not(:last-child):before,
.crumb:not(:last-child):after {
 content: '';
 display: inline-block;
 height: 1px;
 width: 17px;
 position: absolute;
 right: -7px;
 background-color: #fff;
}

.crumb:before {
 top: 6px;
 -moz-transform: rotate(60deg);
 -ms-transform: rotate(60deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(60deg);
 -webkit-transform: rotate(60deg);
 transform: rotate(60deg);
}
.crumb:after {
 bottom: 6px;
 -moz-transform: rotate(120deg);
 -ms-transform: rotate(120deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(120deg);
 -webkit-transform: rotate(120deg);
 transform: rotate(120deg);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>BreadCrumbs</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/3.0.1/normalize.min.css">
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="breadcrumbs.css">
 </head>
 <body>
  
  <ul class="crumb-trail clearfix">
   <li class="crumb pull-left">
    Home
   </li>
   <li class="crumb pull-left">
    Forums
   </li>
   <li class="crumb pull-left">
    Search page
   </li>
   <li class="crumb pull-left">
    Preview: Search criteria
   </li>
  </ul>
  
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```