# How to draw a tab with text in it using HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I will like to make my tab look like this image below:

[image]

But I'm not able to draw this. I have gone to W3Schools and looked at several tutorials online but cannot draw this. I have even played around with the pseudo elements such as `::before` and `::after` but still no luck. Each selection will produce a page.

Comment: Can you post the code that you've tried?

Comment: I suggest using images for such gradient.

Comment: With the shapes like these, gradients and borders, I honestly do not believe this is doable with CSS. You are probably better off using images inside divs or something similar.

Comment: Though your question may get closed because you haven't shown your attempt in the question, I have added an answer because I think it would be useful for others also in future. I would recommend you to add whatever code you had tried in-order to have the question open and be useful for others.

Answer (score 8):

The design that you are looking for is similar to the one described in [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27636373/how-to-make-this-arrow-in-css-only/28196665#28196665). I am posting a separate answer because what you need is a bit more complex than that one due to the presence of gradient background, overlapping triangular areas (on the next item) and box-shadow etc.

The approach used is similar to that answer in the sense that two pseudo-elements are added to each `li` element and they are skewed in the opposite directions to achieve the effect. The below are some of the additional steps that were done for your design:

- A pseudo-element (`:after`) is added to the `ul` and a gradient that goes from semi-transparent white to transparent and then to a semi-transparent black is set as its background image.  Size of this pseudo-element is lesser than the parent `ul` container and this produces the gradient effect.
- Progressively decreasing `z-index` are assigned to each `li` element to bring the earlier element forward and have its triangular bit be above the next element.
- `box-shadow` and `border-right` are added to the `li:before` and `li:after` elements to get the arrow and its shadow.
- A solid white border and two `box-shadow` are added around the `ul`.

The output is responsive as you can see in the "full page view" of the snippet.

```css
ul {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 60px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 30px;
  list-style-type: none;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 0px #DDD, -2px 2px 0px #DDD;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
li {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 33.33%;
  text-indent: -20px;
}
li:before,
li:after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  content: '';
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgb(31, 139, 188);
  border-right: 3px solid rgb(87, 153, 190);
  box-shadow: 3px -2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
li:first-child:before,
li:first-child:after {
  background: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}
li:before {
  top: 0px;
  transform: skewX(45deg);
  transform-origin: left bottom;
  z-index: -1;
}
li:after {
  bottom: 0px;
  transform: skewX(-45deg);
  transform-origin: left top;
  z-index: -2;
}
li:first-child {
  text-indent: 0px;
  z-index: 2;
}
li:nth-of-type(2) {
  z-index: 1;
}
li:last-child {
  width: calc(33.33% + 15px);
}
ul:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: 3px;
  left: 3px;
  height: calc(100% - 6px);
  width: calc(100% - 6px);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 25%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 75%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05));
  border-radius: 25px;
  z-index: 3;
  pointer-events: none;
}

/* if you need hover effects */

li:hover:before,
li:hover:after {
  background: yellowgreen;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Text</li
  ><li>Text</li 
  ><li>Text</li>
  <!-- > is added in next line intentionally to avoid space between inline block elements -->
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also relay on a nav bar and flex.

[codepen to play with](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/grvEqm)  or snippet below to run

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
  /* basicly to help to easily spread evenly childs (float, inline-block, table, .. works  too ) */
  overflow: hidden;
  /*might be usefull to hide links not rounded and last arrow */
  background: #0077AF;
  font-size: 1.8vw; /* 2em;*/
  /* vw used for demo , i do not advise this without mediaqueries to control max and min font-size */
  padding: 0;
  /* reset */
  margin: 0.5em 15px;
  /* whatever */
  border-radius: 2em;
  /* image was rounded */
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px white, 0 0 8px;
  /* draw border and shadow */
  position: relative;
  /* will be used for the web 2.0 glossy thing */
}
nav:before {
  /* the glossy thing */
  content: '';
  /* trigger pseudo */
  position: absolute;
  /* off flow so to stick where needed */
  z-index: 2;
  /* on top */
  pointer-events: none;
  /* click through */
  border-radius: 2.5em;
  /* increase border-radius because smaller than parent */
  top: 5px;
  left: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 -15px 18px -8px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  /* fade outside */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.65), transparent, transparent 80%);
  /* glossy effect drawn */
  filter: blur(3px);
  /* increase a bit the blur/glossy effect, optionnal */
}
a {
  flex: 1;
  /* fill parent and share room according to amount */
  background: inherit;
  /* will be needed to blend with pseudo later */
  color: white;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-decoration: none;
  min-width: 14em;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  /* looked close to your font-family */
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #222;
  padding: 1em;
  margin-right: -.8em;
  /* will hide arrow on last element */
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  /* set this to stick arrow shape */
  overflow: visible;
  /* let arrow show even if outside parent */
}
a:first-of-type {
  margin-left: -1em;
  /* optionnal */
}
a:after {
  /* the right arrow shape */
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  padding: 1.5em;
  box-shadow: 3px -3px 3px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), 5px -5px 6px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  right: -1em;
  /* move outside the square shape */
  top: 0.25em;
  /* tune this if vertcal padding or line-height is reset or change */
  background: inherit;
  /* to blend with parent */
  z-index: 1;
  /* stands on top but under the glossy thing */
}
/* background colors can be modified */

.done {
  background: #FC0000;
}
a:hover {
  background: #DDA265;
}
img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  /* for the show to compare to html/css render */
}
```

```html
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<p>CSS version & hover :</p>
<nav> <a href="#" class="done"> SIZE & CRUST </a>
  <a href="#"> CHEEZE & SAUCE </a>
  <a href="#"> TOPPINGS </a>
</nav>
<p>image version :
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebD59.png" />
</p>
```

Comment: Like the way you've commented below almost every line of the CSS :)