# Vertical Arrowed Process just with 'div' element and css?

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I have to do something similar to the capture (see below) in my website.

I use to do this with Photoshop. But this time I would like to know if this can be done with 3 'div' elements and css.

**Update: this one is similar [How to make this arrow in CSS only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27636373/how-to-make-this-arrow-in-css-only) but mine is vertical.**

With this I get the FIRS arrow div:

```
.arrow_box {
    position: relative;
    background: #88b7d5;
    border: 4px solid #c2e1f5;
}
.arrow_box:after, .arrow_box:before {
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.arrow_box:after {
    border-color: rgba(136, 183, 213, 0);
    border-top-color: #88b7d5;
    border-width: 30px;
    margin-left: -30px;
}
.arrow_box:before {
    border-color: rgba(194, 225, 245, 0);
    border-top-color: #c2e1f5;
    border-width: 36px;
    margin-left: -36px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: @Praveen Kumar It is similar but mine is vertical.

Comment: If you look into the code used there, it should become clear as to how the code has been generated ;) It points you in the right direction

Comment: a **very** quick demo: https://jsfiddle.net/7dvgc4ur/1/

Comment: none of the answers over there are about gradients. is there anything wrong about them ?  example  http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/reRedw

Comment: @jbutler483 thanks, that is what I need. I think this post could be useful for other. This is a vertical arrow. Can you just move your comment as an answer so that I can accept it. Thanks.